I am getting an error Else If without If and don't understand why
I can't see the reason I am getting an error message Else If without If. Does it have something to do with the Msgbox? The problem is I had EXIT SUB after the first IF statement and then a regulur if statement next which never got to the next if statement. When I close out the msgbox it would start the next if isnumeric... and run it which merges the wrong rows that the msgbox if statement warned against.
    Sub MergeTrn()
    Application.Cursor = xlDefault
    Dim activeRow As Long
    Application.DisplayAlerts = False
    activeRow = ActiveCell.Row
    If IsNumeric(ActiveSheet.Cells(activeRow, "C")) And ActiveSheet.Cells(activeRow, "C").Offset(1) = "" Then _
        MsgBox ("Must have a second LRV and/or third LRV to merge the Train info."), vbCritical
    ElseIf IsNumeric(ActiveSheet.Cells(activeRow, "C")) And IsNumeric(ActiveSheet.Cells(activeRow, "C").Offset(1)) And _
        ActiveSheet.Cells(activeRow, "C").Offset(2) = "" Then
            ActiveSheet.Cells(activeRow, "A").Select
            ActiveCell.Resize(2).Merge
            ActiveSheet.Cells(activeRow, "B").Select
            ActiveCell.Resize(2).Merge
            ActiveSheet.Cells(activeRow, "D").Select
            ActiveCell.Resize(2).Merge
            ActiveSheet.Cells(activeRow, "E").Select
            ActiveCell.Resize(2).Merge
            ActiveSheet.Cells(activeRow, "F").Select
            ActiveCell.Resize(2).Merge
            ActiveSheet.Cells(activeRow, "G").Select
    ElseIf IsNumeric(ActiveSheet.Cells(activeRow, "C")) And IsNumeric(ActiveSheet.Cells(activeRow, "C").Offset(1)) And _
        IsNumeric(ActiveSheet.Cells(activeRow, "C").Offset(2)) Then
            ActiveSheet.Cells(activeRow, "A").Select
            ActiveCell.Resize(3).Merge
            ActiveSheet.Cells(activeRow, "B").Select
            ActiveCell.Resize(3).Merge
            ActiveSheet.Cells(activeRow, "D").Select
            ActiveCell.Resize(3).Merge
            ActiveSheet.Cells(activeRow, "E").Select
            ActiveCell.Resize(3).Merge
            ActiveSheet.Cells(activeRow, "F").Select
            ActiveCell.Resize(3).Merge
            ActiveSheet.Cells(activeRow, "G").Select
    End If
    Application.DisplayAlerts = True
End Sub


IIRC how line endings work in VBA the problem is that you ended the If line with an underscore, essentially making the "Then" statement part of the same line, which then becomes a single-line If, which doesn't allow for "ElseIf" or "EndIf". Try removing the underscore.

The reason is the underscore behind the first If statement.
In VBA, the underscore is a character that denotes the next line should be treated as part of the current line.
When you wrote
If [condition1] Then _
    [statement1]
ElseIf [condition2] Then
    [statement2]
EndIf

what really got interpreted was
If [condition1] Then [statement1]


ElseIf [condition2] Then
    [statement2]
EndIf

and that's why you get the error "ElseIf without If".
It would also explain why you never reached the second "regular If" before, when you had the Exit Sub after your message box. Because you probably wrote
If [condition1] Then _
    MsgBox ...
    Exit Sub
If [condition2] Then
    [statement2]
EndIf

and it became
If [condition1] Then MsgBox ...


Exit Sub


If [condition2] Then
    [statement2]
EndIf

and thus would always exit the subroutine.

Merge Rows in Specified Columns Conditionally


The reason behind the error is described in the first answer by LWChris.
This only covers some other issues and improves your code.

Main
Sub MergeTrainInfo()

    Const PROC_TITLE As String = "Merge Train Info"
    
    Dim MergeColumns() As Variant: MergeColumns = Array( _
        "A", "B", "D", "E", "F", "G")
 
    Application.Cursor = xlDefault ' ?
    
    ' This requires that the active cell is in the row of the 1st LRV.
    ' That's rather unreliable.
    ' To fix this, describe the layout of your data in detail
    ' (e.g. the first row is 2 and there are 3 irrelevant rows between each).
    Dim rrg As Range: Set rrg = ActiveCell.EntireRow.Columns("C").Resize(3)
    
    Dim MergeRowsCount As Long, m As Long
    
    If IsNumber(rrg.Cells(1).Value) Then
        If IsNumber(rrg.Cells(2).Value) Then MergeRowsCount = 2
        If IsNumber(rrg.Cells(3).Value) Then MergeRowsCount = 3
        If MergeRowsCount > 0 Then ' has 2nd and/or 3rd LRV
            With rrg.EntireRow.Resize(MergeRowsCount)
                Application.DisplayAlerts = False
                    For m = LBound(MergeColumns) To UBound(MergeColumns)
                        .Columns(MergeColumns(m)).Merge
                    Next m
                Application.DisplayAlerts = True
            End With
        Else ' doesn't have 2nd and/or 3rd LRV
            MsgBox "Must have a second and/or third LRV " _
                & "to merge the Train info!", _
                vbExclamation, PROC_TITLE
        End If
    Else ' doesn't have 1st LRV
        MsgBox "Must have a first LRV to merge the Train info!", _
            vbExclamation, PROC_TITLE
    End If

End Sub

Help
Numbers
''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''
' Purpose:      Returns a boolean indicating whether a value is a number.
' Remarks:      Excludes numbers as String.
''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''
Function IsNumber(ByVal Value As Variant) As Boolean
    Select Case VarType(Value)
        Case vbDouble, vbSingle, vbLong, vbInteger, vbByte
            IsNumber = True
    End Select
End Function

Numbers As String (As an Alternative)
''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''
' Purpose:      Returns a boolean indicating whether a value is numeric
'               but not blank.
' Remarks:      Includes numbers as String.
''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''
Function IsNumericNotBlank(ByVal Value As Variant) As Boolean
    If IsNumeric(Value) Then
        If Len(Value) > 0 Then IsNumericNotBlank = True
    End If
End Function

